# Ionic File Read / Write issue when uninstall / reinstall app (Android)

Tags: android, file, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app that write JSON backups and read them in production since december 2020.
Lately, without any update for this part, the behaviour of Ionic File changed.

I figured out in another thread that apps aren't allowed anymore to read and write in root directory since Android 11, so I changed it to the root/Documents directory, but I sitll have a strange issue.

Here's the behaviour: the app can write and read the file, and re-write it if necessary.
Everything's going well until I uninstall and reinstall the app, then neither read or write work.

In this case, IonicFile.readAsText returns null even if the file exists and is filled.
https://github.com/sebferrer/life-notes/blob/master/front/src/app/infra/importer-exporter.service.ts#L86

And IonicFile.writeExistingFile returns an error with the message "undefinedNaN".
https://github.com/sebferrer/life-notes/blob/master/front/src/app/infra/importer-exporter.service.ts#L146

Here's a workflow to help understand the issue:

1. I install the app. The file doesn't exist yet.
2. I try to read the file via IonicFile.readAsText: that throws the NOT_FOUND_ERR error. This is the expected behaviour as the file doesn't exist yet.
3. I create the file with IonicFile.createFile. Success.
4. I write on it via IonicFile.writeExistingFile. Success.
5. I write on it again via IonicFile.writeExistingFile. Success.
6. I read it via IonicFile.readAsText. Success: IonicFile.readAsText returns the file content.
7. I uninstall the app. The file created before still exists and didn't change.
8. I reinstall the app. The file created before still exists and didn't change.
9. I try to read the file as before via IonicFile.readAsText. **Unexpected behaviour**: no error is thrown, but IonicFile.readAsText returns null instead of the file content.
10. I try to write on the file as before via IonicFile.writeExistingFile. **Unexpected behaviour**: IonicFile.writeExistingFile throws an error this "undefinedNaN" message.

It's like when I uninstall and reinstall the app, the reinstalled app haven't any R/W right about the files generated before. But it worked perfectly before.

I'm so confused right now, any help would be more than welcome.

**Edit:**

It appears to be a permission issue introduced by the newer versions of Android (see comments below).

Comment: "then neither read or write work." do you mean it cannot find the file ? What I know, during uninstall, any files or folders created by the APK is deleted. So if you install the app again, it will create new directories / files. So essentially any old files created from previous installations will never be found.

Comment: No the file still exists as it was created explicitly in the source code. But the app can't read/write it anymore. I edited my message in order to be more clear about the issue.

Comment: "I uninstall the app. The file created before still exists" This is not possible as any file created by an app is erased after uninstall unless you're using a public folder like "Documents" or "Downloads" That being said, with newer version of Android, there is a tighter control over file permissions. 

Lets take the example of your app. Imagine your app creates a file called xyz.txt in the "Downloads" folder. Now i create another app that goes to read your xyz.txt file without user permission. Sounds like a security issue that Android would not allow.

Comment: At first I created the file in a directory generated in the root. I didn't realize how bad this idea was. Since Android 11 I can't even write or read anything here. So I changed it to Documents believing it would be better, but I have this issue. I don't get why is it a security issue, because even if I uninstall and reinstall it, it's the same app, not a different one... This file is a save file, that's why I need it. Do you have any idea of what I should do?

Comment: All modern applications do not use files to save anything. All apps now use a remote server where we connect via database and sync data between apps and server. IF you really need to use files, i suggest you read this documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing usually for my other apps / software, but this is a deliberate choice. This app was designed to work 100% offline. It allows users to note their health data (symptoms, medicines, etc). This is a sensitive data, that's why I developed it in a way that the data would never be stored anywhere but locally. Plus, as it's a notepad tool, it's more convenient for the user to use it offline. There must be a way for this to be possible without the data being on a server, right? :/

Comment: I see all the time in other apps the possibility to let the user chose where he could export save files (that opens the Android native explorer and then the user can select a directory before to tap "Save"). That would be exactly what I want. But I never found this kind of feature with Cordova. Do you know why? Is there any way to do that with Ionic / Cordova?